# Question in Derivation of Lie algebra

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra, textbook-erratum

In Weinberg's QFT Volume 1 Chapter2, he "derives" the Lie algebra from the Lie group as follows

> [...] a connected Lie group [...is a...] group of transformations ($\theta$) that are described by a finite set of real continuous parameters, say $^a$, with each element of the group connected to the identity by a path within the group. The group multiplication law then takes the form
> $$
> T(\bar{\theta}) T(\theta)=T(f(\bar{\theta}, \theta)).\tag{2.2.15}
> $$
> With $^(\bar{\theta},\theta)$ a function of the $\bar{}'s$and $\theta$'s. Taking $\theta^{a} = 0$ as the coordinates of the identity, we must have
> $$
> f^{a}(\bar{\theta}, 0)=f^{a}(0, \theta)=\theta^{a}.\tag{2.2.16}
> $$

Now I wonder whether it writes wrong here, as I think it should be
$$
f^{a}(0, \theta)=\theta^{a},f^{a}(\bar{\theta}, 0)=\bar{\theta}^{a}.
$$

Comment: I think you are correct and it is indeed a trivial typo. Take e.g. $U(1)$ and the fundamental representation $T(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$. Then $f(\bar{\theta},\theta) = \bar{\theta} + \theta$ (mod $2\pi$). Clearly this reproduces your result.

Comment: In my copy it has $f(\theta,0)=f(0,\theta)=\theta$. No bar on he first theta.

Comment: Also no bar in my copy from 1995.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/577540/2451

Comment: I think that is just a typo on my digital version. Another typo pointed by @Qmechanic above is due to the older version. Let me change to a newer version!